# How to insert embedded list in oreintDB2.2 using graph API?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb2.2

I am aware of inserting the embedded list as a document with Document API.As an implementation I choose Graph API and want to know if there is direct way to store an embedded list (records) directly in Graph Vertex. It is feasible to create a separate Vertex for each element in the embedded record and create a link between these Vertices but I am looking to have one vertex with all the details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - even if it is no actual homework.

Answer (score 0):

There is public test code testEmbeddedListAsVertexProperty() using OrientGraph https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/graphdb/src/test/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/blueprints/GraphTest.java

Comment: I was expecting an answer for my one question. But the the link you forwarded answered  all my other questions as well. Thanks a ton Claudio